# fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/main': reference broken

Tags: git, github

Why I got reference broken ? the second time in the last time I created new repo...

tried following things but the error still exists

```
first: git remote set-head origin --auto
other solution: git reset

OTHER Solution
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

should I again create a new repo and why I got this so often...

Comment: What did you do to get to this point?